# How to show $\int_{0}^{1}|f|^{p}|g_{n}-g|^pd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, almost-everywhere

Let $(g_{n})_{n}$ be bounded and measurable where $g_{n}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} g, \mu-$a.e. and $f_{n} \xrightarrow{L^{p}}f$. I need to show that $g_{n}f_{n} \xrightarrow{L^{1}}gf$, and my proof is fine until I need to show that:

$\int_{0}^{1}|f|^{p}|g_{n}-g|^pd\mu\xrightarrow{n \to \infty}0$

Any ideas on how I can show this?

Since  $g_{n}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} g, \mu-$a.e., it follows that $|g_{n}|^{p}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} |g|^p, \mu-$a.e. it is also true that $g_{n} \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and therefore $g_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{p}}g$. Stuck on how to exclude the $|f|^{p}$ from $\int_{0}^{1}|f|^{p}|g_{n}-g|^pd\mu$

Comment: Apply dominated convergence to $|f|^p|g_n-g|^p$...?

Comment: Of course you need $|f|^p$ instead of $|f|$, since $f\in L^p$ and it is not true that $|f|^p\leq |f|$... also if $|g_n|\leq M$ then it is not quite true that $|g_n-g|\leq M$, but this can be easily tweaked

Comment: But besides that, even using DCT would not help me, because $\int |f|^{p}\lim_{n \to \infty}|g_{n}-g|^{p}d\mu$. Why would  $\lim_{n \to \infty}|g_{n}-g|^{p}=0$ neccessarily? All we have given is that $|g_{n}|^{p}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} |g|^{p}, \mu-$a.e.

Comment: If $g_n\to g$ a.e. then $|g_n-g|^p\to 0$ a.e.

Comment: "it is also true that $g_{n} \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb N.$" Why do you say this?

Comment: What is $p$? Does it belong to $[1,\infty)$?